# What exactly is std::labs() there for?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, prototype, math-functions

I read about the `std::abs()` function when browsing [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs).

On that page I have also seen a `std::labs()` function. Which has the same prototype as one of the `std::abs()` overloads (the one for `long`).

```
long abs( long n );

long labs( long n );
```

and

```
long long abs( long long n );

long long llabs( long long n );
```

So,

- What exactly `std::labs()` does?
- Where and when do I use `std::labs()`?
- What is the difference between `std::abs()` and `std::labs()`?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

C++11 was when `std::labs` and `std::llabs` were added. This was part of the partial syncing done to the C++ standard library with the C99 standard library.

You don't really need it in C++ code, because we had a `long` overload of `std::abs` since about forever. But if you have some C code (that by sheer coincidence also compiles with a C++ compiler), and it uses `labs`, you can build it with a C++11 compiler and standard library.

---

In retrospect, there is one marginally useful use case for these functions. And that is when an attempt to use `std::abs` is ambiguous. For instance:

```
template<typename T>
T run_func(T (&f)(T)) {
  return f({});
}
```

Then trying to call `run_func(std::abs);` is ill-formed. We need to either specify the template argument explicitly or cast `std::abs` to the proper type. On the other hand `run_func(std::labs);` isn't ambiguous, and not too verbose.

Still, not *too* useful.

Comment: Re: "some C code (that by sheer coincidence also compiles with a C++ compiler)": And the award for most gratuitous use of the phrase "sheer coincidence" goes to . . .

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, @ruakh.  It is not to be expected that an arbitrary, but valid, C translation unit can be successfully compiled unmodified as C++, unless it has been intentionally written to support that.  Where one can be, that is indeed a coincidence.  If such code happens to furthermore have the same semantics in both languages then that's even more of a coincidence.  How, then, is the use of the phrase "sheer coincidence" in this answer gratuitous?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: C++ grew out of C, and has maintained a high degree of backward-compatibility. Furthermore, even in those areas where the C++ standards have *not* maintained compatibility (or where the C standards have since changed and the C++ standards have not followed), C++ compilers often implicitly extend C++ for compatibility with C. As a result, many real-world C programs can be compiled, with no modifications at all, using many real-world C++ compilers. To claim that this is "sheer coincidence" requires willful obtuseness IMHO.

Comment: @ruakh - C++ has broken compatibility from the onset. The simplest (and idiomatic) `int *p = malloc(sizeof *p);` never did and never will compile in C++. And no compiler ever allowed the implicit conversion from `void*` back, to my knowledge. That's to name one example, anyway. Blame me of being obtuse if you will, but I think your argument stems out of an incomplete view of the languages.

Comment: @ruakh - Furthermore, since the context of my use of the phrase was C99. For the program to be compilable as C++, the person who wrote it would have had to intentionally avoid useful constructs like designated initializers and compound literals. Crippling oneself to be "compatible" with a completely separate language, is unlikely.

Comment: @StoryTeller C and C++ are not completely separate languages. They are overlapping languages. I feel like what you want to say is that one should not count on the fact that C will compile with a C++ compiler, which is totally right.

Comment: @Bobsleigh - If you compare them based on their philosophies, they don't overlap much at all. They are two languages, governed by two separate ISO committees. And that's not without reason. C++ may care to have some interoperability with C, but it certainly never set out to have its compilers be a drop in replacement for C compilers.

Comment: @ruakh, just how high is C++'s compatibility with modern C -- or even with C99 -- is a qualitative question that you and I will not settle.  I'm not even sure we would agree on how to measure.  Ultimately, the point for me is that many people erroneously assume that C++ is a superset of C, and therefore that all C code can safely be compiled as C++.  That assumption should be challenged at every opportunity, as it leads to grief, whether sooner or later.  I have no objection to StoryTeller engaging in a bit of hyperbole in that pursuit, if that's how you choose to regard it.

Comment: As a data point, I'm in the process of converting a relatively small C project (around 10,000 lines) to C++.  The first cut was just using a C++11 compiler instead of a C99 compiler and fixing warnings/errors.  I'm a fairly aggressive C99 user.  The changes I had to make: variables named new, casting *alloc(), static in array sizes in function declarations, compound literals, enum scoping in structs, variable-length arrays, string literals as const char[] vs char[], and designated initializers.  It was not a trivial exercise, although it wasn't particularly difficult.

Comment: I think that's the point -- it's hard to get a non-trivial program that's valid C and C++ accidentally, it takes deliberate work to like that. And the point of reconciling the libraries is presumably to make things a little easier for people who need to do this. It's not for programs that just happen to be lucky.

Comment: @Chris did you end up with something that is idiomatic C++? How sure are you that it does what the C version does?

Comment: @Caleth No, I didn't wind up with idiomatic C++.  I made some fairly large changes, but not architectural ones (e.g. I do some custom I/O stuff; it was an opaque struct in the vein of C's FILE initially, but is now a class).  I've decided a ground-up rewrite would be needed for idiomatic C++, but I'm a lot happier now with a sort of hybrid approach.  I feel more comfortable using the STL instead of maintaining custom data structures.  As for correctness, I have various test data that I can run through the program, and it all passes.  Not definitive, but enough to make me confident.

Comment: @StoryTeller: `return f({});` what it does ? This seems strange syntax.

Comment: @Destructor - Depends on T. For a type like long, it value initializes it (to 0).